# moving questions between MO and math.SE

Tags: discussion

How does one decide if a question is good for MathOverflow or Math.StackExchange?

I've been using the criterion of being "research-level" but that can be subjective.  An expert may consider a question elementary but that is the only subject this person considers.  All others may consider the same question quite advanced.

If a person gets it wrong, what options do they have to move between the two math sites?

Answer (score 11):

Moderators can migrate questions.

I don't think there will ever be a hard or fast rule; it's sort of an odd twist of fate that both sites exist.  I think you just have to judge for yourself what is research-level and what isn't.  If your judgement doesn't match that of the community as a whole, they'll let you know, and you should recalibrate.